# How can I stop guards congregating in yards?

Tags: prison-architect

I have a legendary prisoner who owing to his murdering tendencies needs to be kept in an isolated super max cell.  In it, he has access to most things that he needs including a yard.

The theory is that he will only ever come into contact with armed guards as they are the only ones who can really put him down when he gets into a bit of a rampage.

Unfortunately unarmed guards like to hang around in his personal yard leading to situations such as this:

[image: Murder carnage death ridiculousness]

How can I stop my guards assembling in this yard?  Happy to do this through effective in game zoning/deployment or through the use of mods/file editing.

Comment: If he's that much of a problem restrict his facilities completely and put him in permanent lockdown.

Comment: From "Shawshank Redemption", you could always do what the head guard almost did in the movie while they were tarring the roof:  "Boys I think Mr. Dufresne is about to have an accident."

Comment: On a serious note, I had the same issue with guards -- no supermax prisoner yet, but I had ~15 guards. The ones that weren't deployed, half were in the yard, and half were wandering around outside in front of my prison.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there is no way to keep guards out of an area unless you deploy them all (which is a bad idea) or constantly select them to order them away (which is time-consuming and impractical).

Guards will not randomly wander into cells, so the first thing to do is make the yard accessible from the corridor or outside. This will stop guards entering the cell without a reason so the only time you have to worry is his yard time.

You could also use the tazer rollout and body armor rollout research to make your guards tougher and able to cope with the prisoner.

As a last resort, you could research permanent punishments and permanently lockdown the prisoner. He'll still be fed and will be able to fulfil most of his needs if you put the right furniture in his cell. Guards only need to interct with him when he throws a tantrum.