# How do I prevent my Armed guards from going to minimum security security rooms?

Tags: prison-architect

To deal with certain dangerous individuals, a prison has had to hire multiple armed guards in Prison Architect. They are necessary to suppress or [periodically fusillade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/371842/how-to-make-fearless-deadly-stoic-volatile-prisoners-do-their-time) such inmates.

The prison has, at most times, more staff available than are required for deployments. This is necessary allow "changing of the guard" to deal with staff needs. It is also necessary in order to deal with the fact that more staff is needed at certain times of the day. The prison tends to be more rowdy during dinner than in the middle of the night, for example.

When any guard doesn't know what to do, it gives itself a 'station' task. Try hiring guards without using deployment: they will still station themselves in yards, canteens, common rooms, and cell blocks, spreading out a guard presence over the prison in a kind of 'default deployment'. This default deployment varies by type of guard: for example regular guards are by default deployed to a lot of places, but armed guards to only a few.

One of the rooms that tends to attract such a natural armed guard presence is the security room. Each security level in the prison has its own security room to enable the efficient use of "confidential informants".

Lower security sections of the prison allow for more prison labour and reform. In order to make this reform more effective, snipers and armed guard stations and patrols are not present in these sections, to prevent the constant application of suppression these guard types radiate. Yet the security rooms listed above still cause armed guards to go into these sections of their own volition.

As [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/245192/148546) details, there's no easy way to forbid area access to a type of guard.

How do I cause my armed guards to not to go into the minimum security area, unless I explicitly command them to, without having to understaff my prison?